# Not Getting User Data. Error: The getter 'uid' was called on null

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to follow along this 2 year old Fluter tutorial on Udemy its based on a ride sharing app, but I've come to a halt. am receiving this error

I have done many ways but have not gotten user data. App runs okay but in Debug Console it shows Receiver: null.

**N.B: Flutter SDK version is 2.11.0**

The Code:

```
static void getCurrentUserInfo() async {
    currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String userId = currentFirebaseUser.uid;

    DatabaseReference userRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('user/$userId');

    userRef.once().then((event) {
      final dataSnapshot = event.snapshot;
      if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
        currentUserInfo = UserId.fromSnapShot(dataSnapshot);
      }
    });

  }
```

The UserId Class Code,

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class UserId {
  String fullName;
  String email;
  String phone;
  String id;

  UserId({
    this.fullName,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.id,
  });


  UserId.fromSnapShot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
  {
    id = dataSnapshot.key;
    email = (dataSnapshot.child("email").value.toString());
    fullName = (dataSnapshot.child("name").value.toString());
    phone = (dataSnapshot.child("phone").value.toString());
  }
}
```

The Debug Console

```
E/flutter ( 1624): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 1624): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 1624): Tried calling: uid
E/flutter ( 1624): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter ( 1624): #1      HelperMethods.getCurrentUserInfo
package:cholachol_app/helpers/helpermethodes.dart:20
E/flutter ( 1624): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1624):
```

Comment: the 'userId' is null make sure to check the  'String userId = currentFirebaseUser.uid;'

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't worked in quite some time now:

```
currentFirebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

`currentUser` does not return a `Future`, so the using `await` doesn't have any effect. If you want to wait until the user is signed in, you can [use an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile). Based on the code sample there:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user != null) {
      String userId = user!.uid;

      DatabaseReference userRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('user/$userId');

      userRef.once().then((event) {
        final dataSnapshot = event.snapshot;
       if (dataSnapshot.value != null) {
          currentUserInfo = UserId.fromSnapShot(dataSnapshot);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I recommend keeping the documentation handy, especially when the tutorial you're following a tutorial that may be outdated.